# How to implement container image copy from one project's GCR to another project's GCR in a node js app?

Tags: node.js, gcloud, docker-registry

I have few images in the GCR of say Project A and want to copy these images to the GCR of Project B using a user account say xyz@gmail.com Is this possible?
I also have node js application which uses oauth to authenticate xyz@gmail.com. Earlier I used to do this gcr image copy using shell script where I had used a service account, docker push/pull commands and gcloud container list commands. But now how do I use xyz@gmail.com ie a user account to copy the images in a node application?
Is running shell script application from node the only way? Also , if I have to run shell script using node, I will have to install google sdk and authenticate it. But I do not want to perform the same authentication for xyz@gmail.com 
Please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**From Project A shell , give tag for your image**

`imageProjectA` -> Existing Image Name

`docker tag imageProjectA test.gcr.io/imageNameProjectB:v1`

**Push to Gcr**

`docker push test.gcr.io/imageNameProjectB:v1`

**Pull from Project B shell**

`docker pull test.gcr.io/imageNameProjectB:v1`

**Description:**

Give a suitable name of image which is in Porject A shell. Then Push to Gcr. Then From Project B shell Pull that.  Allocating a tag name for every image is the main thing you have to consider in docker and the version for every docker push , otherwise it will consider all image in latest version.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question